# weave alternative for python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have a function from [here](https://github.com/bsdnoobz/zhang-suen-thinning/blob/master/thinning.py) which uses `weave`. Is there anyway I can run this code in Python 3 without having to rewrite?

The Code:

```
def _thinningIteration(im, iter):
    I, M = im, np.zeros(im.shape, np.uint8)
    expr = """
    for (int i = 1; i < NI[0]-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < NI[1]-1; j++) {
            int p2 = I2(i-1, j);
            int p3 = I2(i-1, j+1);
            int p4 = I2(i, j+1);
            int p5 = I2(i+1, j+1);
            int p6 = I2(i+1, j);
            int p7 = I2(i+1, j-1);
            int p8 = I2(i, j-1);
            int p9 = I2(i-1, j-1);
            int A  = (p2 == 0 && p3 == 1) + (p3 == 0 && p4 == 1) +
                     (p4 == 0 && p5 == 1) + (p5 == 0 && p6 == 1) +
                     (p6 == 0 && p7 == 1) + (p7 == 0 && p8 == 1) +
                     (p8 == 0 && p9 == 1) + (p9 == 0 && p2 == 1);
            int B  = p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9;
            int m1 = iter == 0 ? (p2 * p4 * p6) : (p2 * p4 * p8);
            int m2 = iter == 0 ? (p4 * p6 * p8) : (p2 * p6 * p8);
            if (A == 1 && B >= 2 && B <= 6 && m1 == 0 && m2 == 0) {
                M2(i,j) = 1;
            }
        }
    } 
    """

    weave.inline(expr, ["I", "iter", "M"])
    return (I & ~M)
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run that code in Python 3? Do you get an error message? If so, you need to include it in your question.

Comment: @PM2Ring `ImportError: cannot import name 'weave'`

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't use SciPy, but I just found https://pypi.org/project/weave/ which says "Weave is the stand-alone version of the deprecated Scipy submodule scipy.weave. It is Python 2.x only, and is provided for users that need new versions of Scipy (from which the weave submodule may be removed) but have existing code that still depends on scipy.weave. For new code, users are recommended to use Cython." Also see https://github.com/scipy/weave So it looks like you need to migrate to Cython.

Comment: I can read C, but I don't quite understand that code. But if _you_ understand what that code does it should be fairly straightforward to re-write it to use Numpy. It probably won't be quite as fast, but its speed ought to be acceptable if you can write it in terms of Numpy array operations, since they execute at compiled speed.

Comment: @PM2Ring well the speed of execution is not my concern now and I am also unable to understand what the code does exactly. may be I should ask about it in another question.

Comment: "What does this code do, which I didn't write" questions generally don't do well on SO. It will probably get closed as off-topic. My _guess_ is that `I2` and `M2` are macros that allow you to access the 2D `I` and `M` arrays using `I2(y, x)` notation instead of `I[y][x]`; that may be easy to check from the old `weave` source code.

Answer (score 2):

[Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) can be an alternative solution. It compiles the python code just-in-time and the usage is very neat.

Above code can be re-written in python with decorator:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def _thinningIteration(im, iter_):
    M = np.zeros(im.shape, np.uint8)
    h, w = im.shape
    for i in range(1, h - 1):
        for j in range(1, w - 1):
            p2 = im[i - 1, j]
            p3 = im[i - 1, j + 1]
            p4 = im[i, j + 1]
            p5 = im[i + 1, j + 1]
            p6 = im[i + 1, j]
            p7 = im[i + 1, j - 1]
            p8 = im[i, j - 1]
            p9 = im[i - 1, j - 1]
            A = (p2 == 0 and p3 == 1) + (p3 == 0 and p4 == 1) + \
                (p4 == 0 and p5 == 1) + (p5 == 0 and p6 == 1) + \
                (p6 == 0 and p7 == 1) + (p7 == 0 and p8 == 1) + \
                (p8 == 0 and p9 == 1) + (p9 == 0 and p2 == 1)
            B = p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9
            m1 = (p2 * p4 * p6) if (iter_ == 0) else (p2 * p4 * p8)
            m2 = (p4 * p6 * p8) if (iter_ == 0) else (p2 * p6 * p8)
            if A == 1 and B >= 2 and B <=6 and m1 == 0 and m2 == 0:
                M[i, j] = 1

    return im & ~M
```

It can be executed both in Python-2.x and Python-3.x, with performance close to C. Check [this](https://github.com/yl-1993/zhang-suen-thinning/blob/master/thinning.py) for more details.